# How to create new contacts from nested attributes form in Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building my first semi "real world" rails app (an Open House management app for real estate). I am currently stuck on a "accepts nested attributes" problem. Here are the details... (I've provided all code below)

An open house can have many contacts (attendees), and a contact can attend many open houses. So, I have a join model called Signin. When someone "signs in" to an open house via the Open House > Sign In form, I would like a "sign in" instance to be created along with a contact via nested attributes. Note: Since this is a "has many through", the "Sign in" and "contact" models are not the traditional "parent/child" relationship.

When attempting to submit my Signin form, the form error says "Contact must exist" and the log reports "Unpermitted parameter: :contacts". (I do have strong parameter sit, but perhaps incorrectly).

At this point, I just feel like I've tried everything, but I can't get the form to create a Contact as well as a Signin instance.

The relevant models:

```
class OpenHouse < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :listing
has_many :signins, inverse_of: :open_house
has_many :contacts, through: :signins

class Signin < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :open_house
belongs_to :contact
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
has_many :signins
has_many :open_houses, through: :signins
```

Routes: (Signins are nested within each open house to allow easy sharing of sign in form)

```
resources :open_houses do
resources :signins
end
resources :contacts
```

The Signin Controller:

```
class SigninsController < ApplicationController
def new
@open_house = OpenHouse.find(params[:open_house_id])
@signin = @open_house.signins.build
end

def create
@open_house = OpenHouse.find(params[:open_house_id])
@signin = @open_house.signins.new(signin_params)
if @signin.save
redirect_to @signin, notice: 'You are now signed in'
else
render :new
end
end

def show
@signin = Signin.find(params[:id])
end

private
def signin_params
params.require(:signin).permit( contacts_attributes: [:name, :email, :phone])
end
end
```

Signin Form:

```
<%= form_with model: [ @open_house, @open_house.signins.build ], local: true do |f| %>
<% if @signin.errors.any? %>


<% @signin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<%= msg %>

<% end %>


<% end %>
<%= f.fields_for :contacts do |c| %>

<%= c.label :name %>
<%= c.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your name", class: "form-control" %>


<%= c.label :email %>
<%= c.text_field :email, placeholder: "Your email", class: "form-control" %>


<%= c.label :phone %>
<%= c.text_field :phone, placeholder: "Your phone", class: "form-control" %>

<% end %>
<%= f.submit 'Sign In', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple pluralization error. You need to use `f.fields_for :contact` not `:contacts`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with form_with - so the above may be a better solution, but traditionally you can use multiple fields_for. This will always create a new signing and contact - if that is your intention.

accepts_nested on OpenHouse may be required regardless

```
class OpenHouse < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :signins
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :signins
```

```
= f.fields_for :signins, [f.object.signins.build] do |s|
  = s.fields_for :contract, Contact.new do |c|
```

```
 house = OpenHouse.find(params.require(:open_house_id))
 if house.update(openhouse_params)
  # success
 ...
```